# PostgreSQL not reading '>', '<' operators from java?

Tags: java, postgresql

I send example command from java:

```
ps = "select * from example_table where date > '" +example_date+ "';";
```

In PostgreSQL commandline this command works, if sending from java nothing displays... why?

if you change the operator of '>' on '=', the query works.

Comment: check your datatype of `date` and `example_date` they must same and use `::date`

Comment: _Please_ __don't__ use queries like this in production but rather use prepared statements. That's an enormous security risk, especially if `example_date` is to be directly edited by the user.

Comment: date format: "rrrr-mm-day", example_date format: "rrrr-mm-day"

Comment: Java formats would rather be `yyyy-MM-dd`, `mm` is minute and `day` would be unknown. Btw, check the statement that will be passed to Postgresql to see whether it is the same you're using on the command line.

Comment: What is the value of `example_date`? And what is the data type of the column `date`? (which btw. is a horrible name for a column)

Comment: He treats me operator '>' as '='.

Comment: In example_date is '2000-01-01' in date is '1988-01-01'.

Comment: What's the type of `example_date` ?